# How do drivers work in Windows?

Tags: c, windows, driver

In Linux we can read/write from an associated driver file object and those function calls would be carried by the driver read/write functions. Is it the same in Windows?

Do we associate a file to the driver and access the driver functions by reading/writing to this file?

(I've been programming drivers under Linux and now am trying to understand "the Windows way" to do it.)

Comment: I suggest you are more specific in your questions. A question titled "How do drivers work in microsoft windows?" is likely to get closed.

Comment: The [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) here notes you shouldn't ask a question you can imagine a book worth of answers on. I think you're heading in that direction, even limiting it to "Windows drivers". It would be better if you pick some specific questions about a specific driver for windows written in C

Comment: See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776371(v=ws.10).aspx regarding how device drivers work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Device drivers on Windows do not work in the same way that drivers do on Linux. For a quick introduction to the overall structure of Windows drivers you can check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554678%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There are several classes of drivers but they are not tied to the VFS as in Linux, instead they are represented as nodes in a [tree of devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554721%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff544113%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the purpose of the `DriverEntry` procedure is this:

> > The DriverObject parameter supplies the DriverEntry routine with a pointer to the driver's driver
> >     object, which is allocated by the I/O manager. The DriverEntry routine must fill in the driver
> >     object with entry points for the driver's standard routines.

This means that the I/O manager will call the procedure and you fill out the structure with pointers to the procedures that your driver implememnts. You can [create individual device objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff548397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `IoCreateDevice` and store them in your `DRIVER_OBJECT` structure.

To create a block device style device I believe you want to create a `FILE_DEVICE_DISK` type device.

There is a series of driver creation tutorials by Microsoft, the [second one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be a good place to start.

Comment: What kind of systems programming do you do?

Comment: I don't really do any low level Windows programming any more. I used to work for an antivirus company which is where I did most of my low level Windows programming.